# React Native, Navigate to Nested Tab from Root

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

The structure of my React Navigation is

`DashboardScreen` => `3 Bottom Tabs (1 out of 3, again have)` => `2 Bottom Tabs`

The `DashboardScreen` have three `BottomTabs`

1. `Main`
2. `Profile`
3. `Products`, the `Products` have again two `BottomTabs`

   a. `AllProducts`

   b. `SoldProducts`

What I want to do is, when a product is sold, the product owner will receive a notification, and `onNotificationOpened` from `DashboardScreen.js` I want to navigate to `SoldProducts`. `OneSignal` `onNotificationOpened` is registered in `DashboardScreen.js`. (As far as I know, that's the screen where I should implement my OneSignal's working, I have three more cases here.)

**`DashboardScreen.js`**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      loadUserDetail();
    }
    OneSignal.init(ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID, {
      kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
      kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false,
      kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption: 2,
    });
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', onIds);
}, [isLoading, loadUserDetail, navigation, onOpened]);


const onOpened = useCallback((openResult) => {
    const additionalData = openResult.notification.payload.additionalData;
    if (additionalData.type === 'sold') {
        // From here I want to navigate
        console.log('DashboardScreen, Move to Product Tab, and open SOLD PRODUCT TAB, instead of All Products Tab');
    }
}, []);

return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Main"
      lazy={true}
      tabBar={(props) => (
        <CustomTabBar />
      )}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Products" component={Products} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

Solutions I have tried so far is

```
navigation.dispatch(
  NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'DashboardScreen',
    action: NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'Products',
    }),
  }),
);
```

But that's even not opening the `Products` on `DashboardScreen`.

Also found

```
TabActions.jumpTo('Tab')
```

but `TabActions` only working in `TabComponenet`, means inside `Main`, or `Profile` to switch between `Tabs`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try navigation.navigate('Products') ? does it switch the tab ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But `navigation.navigate('Products')` from `DashboardScreen.js` isn't working. It's not navigating and not giving any error.